# DOMException when playing audio with blob as source

Tags: javascript, html

Whenever I run this code

```
var blob = new Blob(["ninja.mp3"], {type:"audio/mp3"});
var audio = new Audio(URL.createObjectURL(blob));
audio.play().catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I am given the following error

```
DOMException index.html:3
```

I expect it to play the audio file `ninja.mp3` but instead I'm faced with this error. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `var audio = new Audio("ninja.mp3");` does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
var blob = new Blob(["ninja.mp3"], {type:"audio/mp3"});
```

What you just created is a Binary file in your browser's memory which holds the USVString `ninja.mp3`, and for which the browser will send a `Content-Type: audio/mp3` header in some network actions.

*Id est*, you just created an UTF-8 text file. And yes, the MediaElement is not able to read that.

```js
var blob = new Blob(["ninja.mp3"], {type:"audio/mp3"});
// read as text
new Response(blob).text().then(console.log);
```

For a comparison, here is what a real mp3 file looks like when read as text:

```js
fetch("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/agepbh2agnduknz/camera.mp3")
 .then(resp => resp.text())
 .then(console.log)
```

Blob constructor doesn't expect an URL, but a list of Blob parts (which are either USVStrings, Blobs or ArrayBuffers), but **in no way will it ever fetch anything**.

So what you want seems to be as simple as

```
var audio = new Audio("ninja.mp3");
audio.play().catch(console.log);
```

But if one day you need to build a Blob (which you don't now), then be sure that what you pass in the Blob() constructor is actually the binary **content** of your file.

Answer (score -2):

The DOMException interface represents an abnormal event (called an exception) which occurs as a result of calling a method or accessing a property of a web API. This is basically how error conditions are described in web APIs.

I think you call the method wrongly. Pls Check it.